# How Java Compiler treats the modified string at compile time

Tags: java, string, string-comparison, string-concatenation, string-pool

```
public class MyString {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){
        String a="Hello";
        a=a.trim().concat("World");
        String c="HelloWorld";
        System.out.println(a==c);//returns false
    }
```

interning should happen implicitly for string literals .Then why a and c are treated as two different strings?
Will a and c point to same memory reference in string pool?
Hash code returned by a and c are same but a==c returned false. Can someone explain on why the value returned is false.

Comment: A similair [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036434/will-b-and-c-have-same-memory-reference-in-string-pool) was asked a while ago.

Comment: `concat()` does **not** add the returned `String` to the String pool.

Answer (score 1):

> interning should happen implicitly for string literals

It does.

> Then why a and c are treated as two different strings

Because they are two different `String` instances, that happen to have the same content. `a`'s value isn't a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

The method `concat` doesn't add the new created string to the internal of strings. Here is the implementation of `concat`:

```
public String concat(String str) {
    int otherLen = str.length();
    if (otherLen == 0) {
        return this;
    }
    int len = value.length;
    char buf[] = Arrays.copyOf(value, len + otherLen);
    str.getChars(buf, len);
    return new String(buf, true);
}
```

That follow also is documented in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.

It means that when the code executes `String c="HelloWorld";`a new String is created and added to the intern because the previous `HelloWorld` was not present in intern.

The two strings differs by location (reference) so checking them with == returns false.

Comment: Is this applicable for any kind of string modification ?If I apply  "replace" function to a character ,then also will the new string won't get added to internal of strings?

Comment: @Srilakshmi yes it is applicable also to replace.